# Pyspark: How to write table to AWS S3 file

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I try to write a simple file to S3 :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Load environment variables from the .env file
load_dotenv()

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

# My spark configuration
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2')
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

# Create a PySpark DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "John Doe", 30), (2, "Jane Doe", 35), (3, "Jim Brown", 40)], ["id", "name", "age"])

# Write the DataFrame to a CSV file on S3
df.write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("overwrite").save("s3a://bucket/test/store/price.csv")

# Stop the Spark context and Spark session
spark.stop()
```

but this does not save price.csv like the file it opens a new empty folder:

[image]

The same result if I want to save locally This just opens a folder with name price.csv

Comment: Where is it documented that Spark will write a single file? Spark is a distributed application. You can use coalesce(1) on the dataset, at the expense of slowing down your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because spark always writes out a bunch of files.  Remember partitioning, success, etc.

I have written a function I use in databricks to promote that folder with a single partition to a file.

```
#
# Define function to find matching files
# 

# import libraries
import fnmatch

# define function
def get_file_list(path_txt, pattern_txt):
  
  # list of file info objects
  fs_lst = dbutils.fs.ls(path_txt)
  
  # create list of file names
  dir_lst = list()
  for f in fs_lst:
      dir_lst.append(f[1])
      
  # filter file names by pattern
  files_lst = fnmatch.filter(dir_lst, pattern_txt)
  
  # return list
  return(files_lst)
```

This function finds a file in a directory.

```
# 
#  Keep only the single delimited file
#

# Define function
def unwanted_file_cleanup(folder_name, file_name, file_ext):
  try:
    
    # define tmp dir
    tmp_dir = folder_name
    
    # find new file
    tmp_lst = get_file_list(tmp_dir, "part*." + file_ext)
    tmpfile_txt = tmp_dir + "/" + tmp_lst[0]

    # remove old file
    dbutils.fs.rm(file_name, recurse=False)
    
    # copy new file
    dbutils.fs.cp(tmpfile_txt, file_name)
    
    # remove tmp dir, clean up step
    dbutils.fs.rm(tmp_dir, recurse=True)
    
    return True
  
  except Exception as err:
    raise(err)
```

This function turns that output directory into a single file.  You must save the file using a single partition.

Databricks comes with sample temp data.

```
# read in low temps
path1 = "/databricks-datasets/weather/low_temps"
df1 = (
  spark.read                    
  .option("sep", ",")        
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")  
  .csv(path1)               
)

# create temp view
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_low_temps")
```

Read in csv file and create temp view for low temps.

```
# read in low temps
path2 = "/databricks-datasets/weather/high_temps"
df2 = (
  spark.read                    
  .option("sep", ",")        
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")  
  .csv(path2)               
)

# create temp view
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_high_temps")
```

Read in csv file and create temp view for high temps.

```
# make sql string
sql_stmt = """
  select 
    l.date as obs_date,
    h.temp as obs_high_temp,
    l.temp as obs_low_temp
  from 
    tmp_high_temps as h
  join
    tmp_low_temps as l
  on
    h.date = l.date
"""

# execute
df = spark.sql(sql_stmt)

# Write out csv file
path = "/lake/bronze/weather/temp"
(
  df.repartition(1).write
    .format("parquet")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save(path)
)
```

In my use case I am writing a single parquet file which represents the joining of the two datasets.  But the idea of multiple files create by spark regardless of cloud vendor is the same.  Make sure you use repartition(1) to get only one output file of type csv in your case.

[image]

Here are the multiple files I am talking about.

```
#
# create single file
#
unwanted_file_cleanup("/lake/bronze/weather/temp/", "/lake/bronze/weather/temperature-data.parquet", "parquet")
```

The function above finds the partitioned file, moves/renames to parent directory and removes the temporary directory.

```
#
# Show directory listing
#
dbutils.fs.ls("/lake/bronze/weather/")
```

Output:

```
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/lake/bronze/weather/temperature-data.parquet', name='temperature-data.parquet', size=9138)
```